# Using Powershell to recursively search directory for files that only contain zeros

Tags: powershell, search, hex

I have a directory that contains millions of files in binary format.  Some of these files were written to the disk wrong (no idea how).  The files are not empty, but they only contain zeros.  Heres an example http://pastebin.com/5b7jHjgr

I need to search this directory, find the files that are all zeros and write their path out to a file.

I've been experimenting with format-hex and get-content, but my limited powershell experience is tripping me up.  Format-Hex reads the entire file, when I only need the first few bytes, and Get-Content expects text files.

Comment: On which operating system will your script run?

Comment: @Christophe: Does it matter? PowerShell and the BCL are there in any case.

Comment: Depending on OS the pre-installed PowerShell version is not the same. My answer covers PowerShell 3.0+, if Zachary used Windows 7 he would only have 2.0 and need to install the Windows Management Framework to upgrade his PowerShell version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`System.IO.FileStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx) object to read the first `n` bytes of each file.

The following code reads the first ten bytes of each file:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object -Process {

    # Open file for reading
    $file = [System.IO.FileStream]([System.IO.File]::OpenRead($_.FullName))

    # Go through the first ten bytes of the file
    $containsTenZeros = $true
    for( $i = 0; $i -lt $file.Length -and $i -lt 10; $i++ )
    {
        if( $file.ReadByte() -ne 0 )
        {
            $containsTenZeros = $false
        }
    }

    # If the file contains ten zeros then add its full path to List.txt
    if( $containsTenZeros )
    {
        Add-Content -Path List.txt -Value $_.FullName
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, considering they want files that completely consist of zero bytes, I guess reading just _n_ bytes won't really suffice.

Comment: Zachary says "I only need the first few bytes" in his question.

Comment: I understood that as "I only need the first few bytes for determining files that _don't_ consist of all zeroes", as sort of a short-circuit operation for files that are right out from the start.

Comment: I just added -Recurse for Get-ChildItem and it did exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, I added the `-Recurse` option in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use [IO.BinaryReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Get-ChildItem r:\1\ -Recurse -File | Where {
    $bin = [IO.BinaryReader][IO.File]::OpenRead($_.FullName)
    foreach ($byte in $bin.ReadBytes(16)) {
        if ($byte) { $bin.Close(); return $false }
    }
    $bin.Close()
    $true
}
```

In the old PowerShell 2.0 instead of `-File` parameter you'll need to filter it manually:

```
Get-ChildItem r:\1\ -Recurse | Where { $_ -is [IO.FileInfo] } | Where { ..... }
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason for the cast to BinaryReader in there?

Comment: It provides a convenient ReadBytes() method that returns an array of bytes, so I don't have to allocate a buffer myself nor check the file length.

Comment: Oh, right, `OpenRead` returns a `FileStream`. I'm actually surprised you can just _cast_ it to a `BinaryReader`. Or at least I wasn't aware that this would apparently be equivalent to calling `[IO.BinaryReader]::new(...)`.

Comment: Yeah, casting instead of invoking the constructor is also convenient, especially in the old PowerShell 2.0 where constructors aren't exposed on a class.